# Is this a clean BDD/MSpec test?

Tags: unit-testing, bdd, mspec

I have a static class `Cryptographic` that can `Encypt` and `Decrypt` a string. I have written the following specs for this:

```
[Subject(typeof(Cryptographic))]
class When_encrypting_and_decrypting_a_string
{
    Establish context = () => { input = "teststring"; };

    Because of = () =>
    {
        output = Cryptographic.Decrypt(Cryptographic.Encrypt(input));
    };

    It should_decrypt_what_was_encrypted = () => input.ShouldEqual(output);

    static string input;
    static string output;
}

[Subject(typeof(Cryptographic))]
class When_encrypting_and_decrypting_an_empty_string
{
    Establish context = () => { input = string.Empty; };

    Because of = () =>
    {
        output = Cryptographic.Decrypt(Cryptographic.Encrypt(input));
    };

    It should_decrypt_what_was_encrypted = () => input.ShouldEqual(output);

    static string input;
    static string output;
}

[Subject(typeof(Cryptographic))]
class When_encrypting_and_decrypting_a_null_string
{
    Establish context = () => { input = null; };

    Because of = () =>
    {
        output = Cryptographic.Decrypt(Cryptographic.Encrypt(input));
    };

    It should_decrypt_what_was_encrypted = () => input.ShouldEqual(output);

    static string input;
    static string output;
}
```

Is this a clean BDD unittest? Is there anything that can be improved?
A couple of concerns from my side:

1. I might be testing two things here, where I actually should test
   one. I have both `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` in the `Because`.
2. The test involve a lot of copy and paste, all the test only differ by its input argument.  Can or should this be improved, maybe
   by using some sort of row test, or a common base class  or a
   `Behaves` clause instead? I mean readability is now pretty optimal
   but maintainability is not. If I optimize maintainability (DRY) I
   might be trading in readability.

How would you write the tests/specs for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unit test looks like a good starting point. I wonder if it would break if I implemented `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` such that it just returns its respective `input`. Currently, there's no need to encrypt anything which makes me wonder whether the test or the production code have been written first.

As a general rule, if you need to test pairs of input and output, I suggest to have a look at NUnit's `TestCase` et. al. BDD as a tool especially makes sense, but is not limited to, specifying *system* behavior. What you presented here is a single class that does not interact with any other part of the system. While I understand that BDD and the context/specification flavor might have helped to express the expected *unit* behavior, *sometimes* classic unit testing frameworks make more sense. That's especially true if you need a test run for tuples of input and output.

Comment: I think it would make a good and much needed article on when to NOT use the BDD flavor of unit testing. I mean BDD is commonly perceived as TDD vNext ("BDD is TDD done right") but I am sure there is a well defined set of scenarios where choosing TDD tooling is the better choice. This example is part of a public API which is why it doesn't interact with any other part of the system. Something makes me think that specifying/testing public APIs is one of those scenarios.